# Git SVN Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item

Tags: git-svn

I have a SVN server shared by other teams and I have a new project to commit to SVN.

First, I add it to Git control by:

```
git init
```

Then, add all files to Git by:

```
git add .
```

Then, commit all files to Git by:

```
git commit -am "Initial Commit"
```

Then, I link up with SVN by :

```
git svn init https://my_account@my_svn_server_host.com/svn/external/trunk/projectA/
```

where `projectA` folder does not exist. Then, I try to fetch updates from server:

```
git svn fetch
```

Errors arrived.

> W: Filesystem has no item: '/svn/external/!svn/bc/5060/trunk/projectA'
>   path not found at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1801
>
> W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013):
>   Filesystem has no item: '/svn/external/!svn/bc/5060/trunk/projectA'
>   path not found
>
> W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is
>   just searching aggressively for old history. This may take a while on
>   large repositories

Then I try to dcommit:

```
git svn dcommit
```

Then, it gives :

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 541.
```

What did I miss?

I am using Mac OS X 10.7 , MacPorts 2.2.0

**UPDATE:** According to @Wes's answer, here is the result :

```
# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/path/to/my/projectA/.git/
# git checkout -b "mychanges"
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
# git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Oops! Seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do it that way.  `git svn` requires that you have a linear history (ok, git doesn't; svn itself does).  So all of your git work must end up on the end of the commit-tree for svn.

The right thing to do is use `git svn clone` first to mirror the remote repository and then make commits to that checked out version and run `git dcommit`.

Yes, there are other ways to do this, but the way you are doing it above makes a commit before pulling in the remote content, which won't work.

If you're just trying to add all your existing changes to the version from the remote, you can probably do it this way:

```
# git init
# git checkout -b "mychanges"
# git checkout master
# git svn init ....
# git svn fetch
# git checkout mychanges
# git rebase master
# git checkout master
# git merge --ff-only mychanges
# git dcommit
```

That's untested, but it should do what you want.